# Company name in info.plist file - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am planning to release an iPhone app. Where can I set the company's name in the info.plist file?

**UPDATE:**

In addition to the company's name, I wanted to set the Product name and version.

Is iTunes Connect the only option? or we can do it in the project itself.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's normal to set CFBundleIdentifier in the form "com.companyname.productname", but otherwise not sure you need a human readable string.

Comment: You need to set CFBundleIdentifier to the same as the bundle id in the developer center/provisioning portal. The company name which comes below the app in the app store is set in iTunes Connect when you submit your first application. There's no other need to set the company name unless you want to display it in the app, in which case you don't use info.plist for that.

Comment: @Thomas: I wanted this name to appear in the App store as my company's name.

Comment: It's not in XCode or in code, it's in iTunes Connect !

Comment: You set it in itunes connect when you submit your first application. :) Nothing to do with the info.plist, or the app at all. :) You can't change it for different apps. Every app you submit in that developer account has the same company name.

Comment: @:Thomas : Thanks . How can I set the Version number and the App name. Can the App name I specify in info.plist file be overridden in the iTunes connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name that appears under your application in the app store is set in iTunes connect. You can't set it per app... the name is a one time thing - you can't change this, unless you buy a new developer account!

You set the name that displays **under the application icon** on the home screen of your iphone in info.plist. This is the `Bundle display name`. The application title **in the app store** is set **in itunes connect** (and the version number - although you **do** have to specify a version number in XCode as well, and if the version number differs from XCode to ITunes connect - I've heard - your app will be rejected).

Just go through the process (like everyone else) and you'll understand.

Comment: Does it mean that, the name that appears in springboard alone can be set through info.plist file? :)

Comment: yep... thats the Bundle display name. You can set it and see it in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to set it in the Info.plist but you can in the Projects Settings.

Comment: I found a field named "Organization name" in Project general settings. Will setting a name here be updated in App store?

Comment: Just in XCode. in the AppStore the name visible is the name of your company account used to post your application.

Comment: Thanks MathieuF. I got it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

everything you want, is here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html